# Appending new data to existing data in database row?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working with an MSACCESS database (.mdb) and need to update a selection of rows 'notes' column. Each of the rows has notes I've entered already, however I need to add a static note to the existing notes that are already there for each record. If I were programming this I would do the following:

```
var notes = "these notes"
var notes = "more notes to be added on top of\n\n" + notes
```

Can I do something like below?

```
UPDATE tblGages
SET notes = notes + 'new notes here'
WHERE ToolID
IN ("id1", "id2", id3", etc)
```

Comment: If notes is just a text field (Memo type?), then yes, that should work. Although, advise using `&` for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following solved my problem!

```
UPDATE tblGages
SET Notes = tblGages.Notes + "MORE NOTES HERE"
WHERE IN ("id1", "id2", "id3")
```

Comment: That should fail without field name in WHERE clause.